# Avoid AutoDoc Generation Of @param & @return

Tags: java, android, documentation

In a statically typed language the @return and @param can often be redundant to include in the docs. In fact Android doesn't include them in their own conventions:

[Java Coding Style Conventions](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#use-javadoc-standard-comments)

Unfortunately by default if you use `/**` to create doc comments, you get the boilerplate @param and @return

```
   /**
     * Some function with some purpose
     * @param variableName
     * @return
     */
```

Can I turn off the auto generation of @param and @return when I create doc comments in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best solution I've found is just using `/*` to start a comment instead of `/**`